# Can not launch tlp

Tags: software-installation, tlp

I have installed [tlp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/tlp.8.html) in Kubuntu 19.04.   I tried to launch it from the Discover application and a message appears:

> cannot launch tlp

What do I need to do to confirm it's working?

Answer (score 2):

**TLP** runs as a service. It is started from the terminal and it has no GUI.

After you install TLP, you run it for the first time using this command in the terminal:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Then you do not need to run it again. It will run automatically with each reboot.

You can check the status of the TLP service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl status tlp.service
```

You will get an output like this:

```
● tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-08-27 23:06:37 +03; 3 days ago
     Docs: https://linrunner.de/tlp
 Main PID: 2374 (code=exited, status=0)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/tlp.service
```

`enabled` means it will run automatically every time the system starts.

---

To see TLP's extended status information, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo tlp-stat
```

Comment: The answer was very good. I applied and it works.Thank you.

Comment: @AbhedaYoga I am glad it helped. You are most welcome.